# xslt doesn't filter out pdb files

Tags: xslt, wix

I try to use xslt file to filter out the pdb files when harvest files with heat. However the pdb files are still there. What am I missing? Here is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"                                
xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="pdf-search1"     match="wi:Component[contains(wi:File/@Source='$(var.StageDirXFire)', '.pdf')]" use="@Id"/>

<xsl:template match="wi:Component[key('pdf-search1', @Id)]"/>
<xsl:template match="wi:ComponentRef[key('pdf-search1', @Id)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wix">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="PdbToRemove"
           match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]"
           use="@Id" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[self::wix:Component or self::wix:ComponentRef]
                        [key('PdbToRemove', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't really know a lot about xslt but I just so happened to have done the exact same thing you needed for one of my installer projects. I ended up with this xslt (and some other stuff that I removed) after googling around for a while.